# How to handle negative integer when converting them to strings?

Tags: c, string, integer, logic

I need to convert integer to a string, be it negative or positive. 
So far i able to convert positive integers to strings using the following code.
But not the negative ones. How can i handle them properly to convert them to strings.
Here is the code that i was using.

Thanks

Rajat!

```
 /*
  * C Program which Converts an Integer to String & vice-versa
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void tostring(char [], int);


int main()
{
char str[10];
int num, result;

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
tostring(str, num);
printf("Number converted to string: %s\n", str);


return 0;
}

void tostring(char str[], int num)
  {
    int i, rem, len = 0, n;

if(num<0)
{
    n=(-1)*(num);

}
else
{
    n=num;
}
while (n != 0)
{
    len++;
    n /= 10;
}
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    rem = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
    str[len - (i + 1)] = rem + '0';
}
str[len] = '\0';
   }
```

Comment: Are you purposefully avoiding `itoa` and `sprintf` for practice reasons? Because they pretty much replace all of your code with one line...

Comment: Yes @Amadan I am purposefully avoiding it. I want to write my own code to perform that. :) Thanks!

Comment: "I want to write my own code" - so where is your own code or at least your own thoughts about how to convert a negative value? A majro part of programming is to think a bit beforeimplementing. This one requires elementary school math basics.

Answer (score 3):

Before doing anything else, see if `n` is negative. If it is, start the output with the sign `-` (make sure `len` is also one more than it would be otherwise, and that your stringification starts one character later), make `n` positive, and continue as you were doing it before.

Comment: I tried doing that , But it gives me weird outputs which is similar to the output that i get if i don't convert the negative number to positive.

Comment: Then please show what you are doing. We can't find errors we're not told about. And if it's for practice, it'd be counterproductive for me to just do it for you, so I'll stay at hints about your code, and write none of my own.

Comment: I have edited the code , This is what i am getting      Enter a number: -67
Number converted to string: *)

Comment: Note that you convert `n` to be positive (btw, `n = (-1)*(num)` is the same as `n = -num`), but you later use `num`, not `n`, which remained negative (so you end up subtracting the digits from `'0'`, instead of adding them, which produces weird characters). You also do not enter the sign `'-'` into `str`.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder how i missed that part. I will try resolving it. and will update the same here

Answer (score 0):

You have to be really wary of "corner-case" like many other have said :

- You can't have the positive value of a negative int in an int
  The range value of an int is [MIN; +MIN -1], like –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 for a 4 byte int.
  So, if you have –2,147,483,648 and you *-1, you will not have 2,147,483,648 since it will overflow the int capacity
- Your loop for finding the len of int is "bad", because you don't take negative number in count (but I suppose this is the purpose of this post) and you don't take car of the corner case 0 ("len" value is 0 but must be 1).

So, how can you make this function ?

1 : Fix the int len calculation

```
size_t len = 1;

for (int n = number;  n <= -10 || 10 <= n; n /= 10) {
    ++len;
}
```

2 : Fix the "digit to char" loop

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    str[len - i - 1] = abs(number % 10) + '0';
    number /= 10;
}
str[len] = '\0';
```

There. The only thing that left is to put "-" in the beginning and have an offset for negative case number.
You can have an offset variable (fix the "digit to char loop" if you use it) or you can simply do "++str".

There, you can do the function on your own now, I pratically gived you the answer.

---

On a funny note, you can skip the "abs" function if you simply do the following :

```
void tostring(char *str, int number)
{
    char   *digit = "9876543210123456789" + 9;
    size_t len    = 1;

    if (number < 0) {
        // TODO : Put '-' in the first case
        // TODO : Make str to be *str[1]
    }

    for (int n = number;  n <= -10 || 10 <= n; n /= 10) {
        ++len;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        str[len - i - 1] = digit[number % 10];
        number /= 10;
    }
    str[len] = '\0';
}
```

If you don't understand how this work, take your time and read how pointer work (especially pointer arithmetic).

Comment: looping twice dividing which may take up to 80 clock cycles.

Comment: @P__J__ What do you mean ? I understand that on this situation, calculating the futur len of the string is a bit useless, but the function as it is very unsecure since it using "str" without knowing if there is enough space. So a "better" version of this function will have to malloc, and then it make sense to have the final length (although you can still just malloc 64 char and simply reverse the final string). Futhermore, I tried to keep the same algorithm that *In-terra Weekend Projects* use.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by the help from @Amadan .
Here is the code that i am using. Please feel free to tell me a more better way to solve this issue.
Thanks
Rajat

```
/*
* C Program which Converts an Integer to String & vice-versa
 */
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <math.h>

 void tostring(char [], int);


 int main()
 {
     char str[10];
     int num, result;

     printf("Enter a number: ");
     scanf("%d", &num);
     tostring(str, num);
     printf("Number converted to string: %s\n", str);


     return 0;
  }

 void tostring(char str[], int num)
 {
     int i, rem, len = 0, n;
     bool flag=0;
     if(num<0)
   {
       n=-num;
       flag=1;
   }
     else
   {
       n=num;
       flag=0;
   }
   while (n != 0)
   {
       len++;

       n /= 10;


    }
   if(flag==1)
    {
        num=-1*num;
        str[0]='-';

     }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {

        rem = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        if(flag==1)
        {
            str[len - (i)] = rem + '0';

        }
        else
        {
           str[len - (i + 1)] = rem + '0';
        }   



       }
       if(flag==1)
       {
           str[len+1] = '\0';
       }
       else
       {
           str[len] = '\0';
       }



    }
```

Comment: You just don't take in count the corner case that many have told you about (including me), so I will say : your code is bugged. Maybe fix it ?

Comment: Thanks tom! I am actually using this function for converting the sensor data to string which i know will always be within the limits. Its a bit urgent at the moment, I will try to fix this whenever things get  a bit easier. :)

Answer (score -1):

Just use `sprintf` function as below,

```
sprintf(str,"%i",num);
```

So the modified code will be,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void tostring(char [], int);


int main()
{
char str[10];
int num, result;

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
//tostring(str, num);
sprintf(str,"%i",num);
printf("Number converted to string: %s\n", str);


return 0;
}

void tostring(char str[], int num)
  {
    int i, rem, len = 0, n;

n =num;
while (n != 0)
{
    len++;
    n /= 10;
}
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    rem = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
    str[len - (i + 1)] = rem + '0';
}
str[len] = '\0';
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have the function which works with any base (you need just to find enough chars to represent digits) but it will not work in one corner case (can you find the case?)

```
static const char Digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ";

static char *reverse(char *s, size_t len)
{
    size_t pos;

    for(pos = 0; pos < len / 2; pos++)
    {
        char tmp = s[pos];

        s[pos] = s[len - pos - 1];
        s[len - pos - 1] = tmp;
    }
    return s;
}

char *toString(char *buff, int n, unsigned base)
{
    int saved = n;
    char *savedbuff = buff;

    n = n < 0 ? -n : n;                       // <= there is one number which will cause problems. Which one?
    do
    {
        *buff++ = Digits[n % base];
        n /= base;
    }while(n);
    if(saved < 0) *buff++ = '-';
    *buff = 0;
    return reverse(savedbuff, buff - savedbuff);
}

int main()
{
    char buff[50];
    printf("%s\n", toString(buff, -255,12)); // 12 base :)
    printf("%s\n", toString(buff, -976,10)); // 10 base 
    printf("%s\n", toString(buff, -976,8));  // or maybe octal ?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: DV? any comment